# PHP Dynamic navigation with active tag

Tags: php

I am trying my hand at creating a dynamic PHP navigation menu using seperate PHP files.

I currently have the following files:

**currentPage.php** - This file will fetch the current page name of whatever page the user is on

```
<?php
    $page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $_SESSION['page'] = $page;
?>
```

**fetchPages** - This file should fetch all active pages from a SQL database and create a list of them adding an active class to the corresponding page title text when the user is on the corresponding page

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'currentPage.php';

$sql = "SELECT pageTitle, pageUrl FROM pages ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
}
else{
    $msg = "No pages found";
}
?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <a class="<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == $_SESSION['page']){echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $row['pageUrl'] ?>"><?php echo $row['pageTitle'];?></a>
<?php } ?>
<br>
```

Issue is it doesn't work since it adds an "active" class to all rows. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you auto_start sessions? (If not, all of your PHP scripts are missing a `session_start();` https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: `=` assigns a value, `==` and `===` compare values

Comment: @brombeer Thanks for your comments. I did start the session in the connect file. And change the = to == unfortunately this did not fix the issue

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to stick this value into the session in the first place here. Just remove the session part, and access `$page` inside your if condition.

Comment: You need to compare `$row['pageUrl']` to your current page. Right now you're comparing `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` - which will always be true for any iteration

Comment: @CBroeI have tried this approach also with no luck. It removes the active class for all pages but does not add to the active one, despite the page variable being set

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use session initialization at the beginning - `session_start();`
2. `if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $_SESSION['page'])` - here you assign a value, not compare. Use `==` or `===`
3. There is an error in the logic - you will get the strings from the database, but do not compare the values from the database with the current page, but compare `PHP_SELF` with `$_SESSION['page']` and always get true.
   It should be something like this:

```php
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
include 'currentPage.php';

$sql = "SELECT pageTitle, pageUrl FROM pages ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
}
else{
    $msg = "No pages found";
}
?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <a class="<?php if(echo $row['pageUrl'] == $_SESSION['page']){echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $row['pageUrl'] ?>"><?php echo $row['pageTitle'];?></a>
<?php } ?>
<br>
```

4. Writing data to `$_SESSION['page']` is not a good idea

Comment: `<?php if(echo $row['pageUrl'] ==` ??? What's that supposed to do? Why is "_Writing data to $_SESSION['page']_" not a good idea?